# Оцените мой код

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Всем привет, вчера я скачал python.
Попробовал написать создание простого списка с вводом данных от пользователя. При указании длины списка проверяется, чтобы вводилось только положительное число без букв и др. символов.
Прошу подсказать, можно ли его как-то причесать и упростить?
Вот так получилось:

```
a = None
print("\nЗапущен алгоритм составления списка.")
user_input = input("Укажите длину списка: ")

if user_input.isnumeric() == True and int(user_input) > 0:
    a = True
else:
    while a != True:
        if user_input.isnumeric() != True:
            user_input = input("\nДля указания длины списка допускаются только числа.\nУкажите 
длину списка: ")
        elif int(user_input) <= 0:
        user_input = input("\nСписок не может быть пустым.\nУкажите длину списка: ")
        else: break
user_list = []
print("\nСписок для", user_input, "значений успешно создан!")

for stroke in range (int(user_input)):
    stroke += 1
    if stroke == 1:
        user_list.append(input("Введите первое значение в списке: "))
    else:
        user_list.append(input("Введите " f'{stroke}' "-е значение в списке: "))

user_input = input("\nДанные внесены в список.\nПоказать содержимое? (Да\Нет): ")
while user_input != "Да" and  user_input != "да":
    user_input = input('\nТребуется ответ "Да"или "Нет".\nПоказать содержимое?: ')
else:
    print("\n", user_list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно и покомпактнее сделать:

```
print("\nЗапущен алгоритм составления списка.")

while True:
    user_input = input("Укажите длину списка: ")
    
    if user_input.isdigit() and int(user_input) > 0:
        break
    else:
        print("\nДопускаются только положительные числа.")
        
user_list = []

print(f"\nСписок для {user_input} значений успешно создан!")

for stroke in range(1, int(user_input) + 1):
    user_list.append(input(f"Введите {stroke}-е значение в списке: "))

user_input = input("\nДанные внесены в список. Показать содержимое? (Да/Нет): ")

while user_input.lower() not in ["да", "нет"]:
    user_input = input('\nТребуется ответ "Да" или "Нет".\nПоказать содержимое?: ')

if user_input.lower() == "да":
    print("\n", user_list)
```

Comment: `and int(user_input)>0` лишнее

Comment: Не согласен. Какой толк в том, что можно будет ввести 0? Ура, вы создали список из 0 элементов...

Comment: действительно, не продумал этот момент =)

Comment: Если бы ТС написал "натуральное число" вместо "положительное число", то этой неоднозначности бы не было

Comment: Спасибо за обратную связь!

Comment: А в чем будет принципиальная разница между "натуральное" и "положительное" в данном случае? Как это повлияет на код?

Comment: @Konstantin607 разница на 0, который "положительное", но не "натуральное". Если "положительное", то допустим список нулевого размера, т.е. пустой.

Comment: @Алексей Р, спасибо!

Comment: @Konstantin607, да, и неплохо бы ограничить размер списка "сверху", а то при вводе списка, например, из 12456789 элементов пользователь слишком долго будет вводить данные :)

Comment: @Алексей Р, вы имеете ввиду, если указана длина списка, например, больше 10, то все фигня давай по новой?